# What is the proper way to dispose the image in Android

Tags: android, android-image

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView imageView1;
    Bitmap s;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // logHeap("ECAonCreate");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.launchimage20481496);
        // s = decodeFil3e(R.drawable.launchimage20481496);
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    private Bitmap decodeFil3e(int f) {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), f, o);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();
        int[] resized = ImageSize(new int[] { o.outWidth, o.outHeight }, width,
                height);

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(o2, resized[0], resized[1]);
        o2.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
        o = null;
        o2 = null;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), f, o2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        imageView1.setBackgroundResource(0);
        imageView1 = null;
        System.gc();
        System.gc();
        logHeap("ECAonDestroyonClick");
    };

    public static int[] ImageSize(int[] imgSize, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        int[] size = new int[2];
        try {
            for (double i = 1; i <= 20; i += 0.1) {
                double height = imgSize[1] / i;
                double width = imgSize[0] / i;
                if (height < maxHeight && width < maxWidth) {
                    size[0] = (int) width;
                    size[1] = (int) height;
                    return size;
                }
            }
            return imgSize;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return size;

        }
    }

    public static void logHeap(String functionname) {
        Double allocated = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize())
                / new Double((1048576));
        Double available = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapSize()) / 1048576.0;
        Double free = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize()) / 1048576.0;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        Log.d("tag", "debug. =================================");
        Log.d("tag", "debug.heap native: allocated " + df.format(allocated)
                + "MB of " + df.format(available) + "MB (" + df.format(free)
                + "MB free)");
        Log.d("tag",
                "functionname:"
                        + functionname
                        + ":debug.memory: allocated: "
                        + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime()
                                .totalMemory() / 1048576))
                        + "MB of "
                        + df.format(new Double(
                                Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1048576))
                        + "MB ("
                        + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime()
                                .freeMemory() / 1048576)) + "MB free)");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        logHeap("ECAonResume");
    };

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent a = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(a);
        finish();
        //imageView1.setBackgroundResource(0);
        //imageView1 = null;
        //System.gc();
        //System.gc();
        //logHeap("ECAonDestroyonClick");
    }

}
```

In the picture 1 heap size is not reduced:
[image]

you can see the heap size reduced:
[image]

I am facing a strange issue.
My heap memory is freed , if I uncomment the below code from onClick event

```
//      imageView1.setBackgroundResource(0);
//      imageView1 = null;
//      System.gc();
//      System.gc();
//      logHeap("ECAonDestroyonClick");
```

But if I place the same code in the onDestory event, nothing works.
Where do I make mistake?
What is the proper way to dispose the image?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.
```

This is one phrase you'll come across frequently in android while you try to load several large bitmaps in your program. And Why? Because the heap size available to an application is limited and large bitmaps are the easiest way of exhausting it.
So how do you work around it?

Comment: Just found this link which is useful to me as an Android beginner https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: FWIW, it might be that System.gc is *deferred*, when in middle of activity's `onDestroy`. If it works as expected during `onClick`, then you are probably doing the right call. If your concern is getting OutOfMemoryErrors, then design a test that causes that error. Then modify your code to release each bitmap the way you think it should be deleted, and see if the error goes away, even if you repeat the test over and over (so, allocating far beyond the original OOM, but with proper release inbetween). Should not need to ever call `System.gc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.mathjax_issues;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView imageView1;
    Bitmap s;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // logHeap("ECAonCreate");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // s = decodeFil3e(R.drawable.launchimage20481496);
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    private Bitmap decodeFil3e(int f) {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), f, o);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();
        int[] resized = ImageSize(new int[] { o.outWidth, o.outHeight }, width,
                height);

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(o2, resized[0], resized[1]);
        o2.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
        o = null;
        o2 = null;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), f, o2);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("jarvis", "on desttroy executed");
        imageView1.setBackgroundResource(0);
        imageView1 = null;
        logHeap("ECAonDestroyonClick");
        System.gc();
        logHeap("ECAonDestroyonClick");

    };

    public static int[] ImageSize(int[] imgSize, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        int[] size = new int[2];
        try {
            for (double i = 1; i <= 20; i += 0.1) {
                double height = imgSize[1] / i;
                double width = imgSize[0] / i;
                if (height < maxHeight && width < maxWidth) {
                    size[0] = (int) width;
                    size[1] = (int) height;
                    return size;
                }
            }
            return imgSize;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return size;

        }
    }

    public static void logHeap(String functionname) {
        Double allocated = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize())
                / new Double((1048576));
        Double available = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapSize()) / 1048576.0;
        Double free = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize()) / 1048576.0;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        Log.e("tag", "debug. =================================");
        Log.e("tag", "debug.heap native: allocated " + df.format(allocated)
                + "MB of " + df.format(available) + "MB (" + df.format(free)
                + "MB free)");
        Log.e("tag",
                "functionname:"
                        + functionname
                        + ":debug.memory: allocated: "
                        + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime()
                                .totalMemory() / 1048576))
                        + "MB of "
                        + df.format(new Double(
                                Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1048576))
                        + "MB ("
                        + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime()
                                .freeMemory() / 1048576)) + "MB free)");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        logHeap("ECAonResume");
    };

    public void onClick(View v) {

       /* Intent a = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(a);
        finish();*/
        //imageView1.setBackgroundResource(0);
        //imageView1 = null;
        //System.gc();
        //System.gc();
        //logHeap("ECAonDestroyonClick");

    }

}
```

[image]